# How to use utf8 in multiple choices ModelForm in django?

Tags: django, utf-8, django-forms

I have a model with multiple choice optons:

```
class Interest(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    smoking = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, choices=TRIPLE_CHOICES)
```

I in the model forms I have:

```
class InterestForm(forms.ModelForm):        
    class Meta:
        model= Interest
        fields = ('smoking')
```

I want to use Persian multiple choices for the field:

```
TRIPLE_CHOICES = (
    ('بله','بله'),
    ('خیر','خیر'),
    ('گاهی','گاهی'),
             )
```

I have put # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- above all the pages. However the form does not validate unless I choose one of the pair in the tuples in ASCII, that is:

```
TRIPLE_CHOICES = (
    ('بله','yes'),
    ('خیر','no'),
    ('sometimes','گاهی'),
             )
```

How should I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

at the begin of your file, just after

```
# -- coding: utf-8
```

Comment: Worked like charm! Thanks